# Eigenvalues of a fourth order differential equation with boundary conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am stuck trying to figure out the following eigenvalue equation.

$x, y$ exist from $[0,T]$, and vanish at the end points.

$\lambda$ is the eigenvalue.

$$\dfrac{d^4x}{dt^4} + (\omega^2 -2\lambda)\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\lambda^2x 
$$

Initially I had the following two equations:

$$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} -\omega\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \lambda x \\ \dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}        
 + \omega\dfrac{dx}{dt}   = \lambda y
$$

Decoupling them gives the previous equation. $\omega$ is a positive number. Kindly help!

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation is:

$$P(\mu)=\mu^4+(\omega^2-2\lambda)\mu^2+\lambda^2$$

Where $\mu$ are your eigenvectors.

Note that $u=\mu^2$ results in an quadratic equation, for which you can simply find its roots.

$$P(u)=u^2+(\omega^2-2\lambda)u+\lambda^2$$

$$u_{1/2}=\frac{-(\omega^2-2\lambda)\pm\sqrt{(\omega^2-2\lambda)^2-4\lambda^2}}{2}$$

Now use $u=\mu^2$ to determin the eigenvalues $\mu$.